# Gmail console App C#

Tags: c#, console

I'm trying to figure out why I am getting the error `"Cannot assign to 'loggedIn' because it is a method group"` within my menu method. Any help will be appreciated. Code is below:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace GmailClient
{
  class Program
{
    static string userName="";
    static string passWord="";

    public static bool loggedIn()
    {
        if (userName == "")
        {
            if (passWord == "")
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
    public static void menu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loading menu.");
        if ( loggedIn = false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("__________Menu__________");
            Console.WriteLine("1) Enter your Gmail credentials");
            Console.WriteLine("2) Exit the Console");
            Console.WriteLine("________________________");
            Console.WriteLine("What do you want to do?");

            int userchoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (userchoice == 1)
            {
                credentials();
            }
            else if (userchoice == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hope to see you soon!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
        else if (loggedIn = true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("__________Menu__________");
            Console.WriteLine("1) Enter your Gmail credentials");
            Console.WriteLine("2) Check your inbox");
            Console.WriteLine("3) Send an e-mail");
            Console.WriteLine("4) Exit the Console");
            Console.WriteLine("________________________");
            Console.WriteLine("What do you want to do?");

            int userchoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (userchoice == 1)
            {
                credentials();
            }
            else if (userchoice ==2)
            {
                getMail();
            }
            else if (userchoice ==3)
            {
                sendMail();
            }
            else if (userchoice ==4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hope to see you soon!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void credentials()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your Gmail address:");
        userName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your Gmail password:");
        passWord = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static void getMail()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loading inbox messages");
    }
    public static void sendMail()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Under Construction");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Aside from anything else, I'd change `loggedIn` from a method to a property, and change the implementation to just: `return userName != "" && password != "";`. Now would also be a very good time to learn and start following .NET naming conventions.

Comment: loggedIn has to be a method for the project requirements. I'll keep this advice in mind for the future.

Comment: I would strongly suggest talking to whoever wrote the project requirements then. (I assume this is a school project or something similar.) For a start, it doesn't actually indicate whether or not you're logged in - it indicates whether or not the user has entered a username and password. That's not the same thing. Next, the whole project looks like it's basically Java code converted to C# - that's *not* an appropriate thing to be teaching new C# developers.

Comment: It is a school project. I think we will be expanding the project throughout the semester as this is part 1 and we should also have a part 2 and part 3 before the class ends. I'll trust your judgement on the Java part considering this is my first programming experience at all.

Comment: Right. Schools should *absolutely* follow normal naming conventions for the programming languages they're using. Maybe you can't use a property yet because you haven't covered them - but there's no excuse for the naming issue. If there's any way you can complain, please do so - as much for the future students as for yourself. I would be deeply suspicious of the quality of the rest of the teaching, with such a basic problem to start with. Best of luck improving the situation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `if ( loggedIn = false)` to `if (!loggedIn())` and `if (loggedIn = true)` to `if (loggedIn())`.

Also, when using an `if` condition check, don't use a single equals `=`. `=` is assignment (e.g., You are assigning a value to a variable `variable = "value"`). Use double equals `==` when comparing (e.g., `if (variable == true) ...`).

In the case of your code, `loggedIn` is defined as a **method/function**. Your code was treating it as a property/variable.

Comment: ... and ideally change it to a property.

Comment: Thanks! This works! I can't accept your answer for 8 minutes though? I'm new to SO so I'm not entirely sure of all the rules and ect.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. Yeah after that 8 minute threshold you'll be able to accept the answer.